# displaying timeout message not force close the app

Tags: android

I want to display a timeout message to user not force close the application

this is my code

```
String xml = null;

BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, 1000);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000);

// defaultHttpClient
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

try {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
return xml;
```

if the connection timeout the app force close and give me this error :

```
  org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /xx.xx.xx.xx:xx timed out
```

Comment: You might want to catch this Exception in that case.

Comment: `catch (org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException e) {}` as for showing something to the user, more context is needed (such as where you're running the code from), but I suggest you try something yourself.

Comment: Can you please explain about the Exceptions

Comment: Best resource is the Java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: thank you for the link, if anyone understand what I want please heelp